Service control policy for mandatory tags in AWS?
I want my AWS account to set 3 tags as mandatory: Owner, Environment and Project. However, I also want other tags to be allowed.
In the following snippet I have defined the policy for the action on lambdas, as I am testing applying to resources with terraform.
None of the variants I have tested so far deny if the Project, Owner or Environment do not exist, but without restricting the ability to apply arbitrary tags.
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RequireOwnerTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "lambda:TagResource",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Owner": "?"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "RequireValidEnvironmentTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "lambda:TagResource",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Environment": [
            "dev",
            "test",
            "pre",
            "pro"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "RequireProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "lambda:TagResource",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Project": "?"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

